# working with annotate django

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

What I want to do is pull all the teams that have more than 12 players on it. I am told i need to use .annotate with a count to get it done. I am looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/ but dont understand how to do a query on that and put it into html. I am assuming pull a query and then do html to make it do the right count.

the question for the assignmnt is ...show all teams that have had 12 or more players, past and present. (HINT: Look up the Django annotate function.)

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import League, Team, Player

from . import team_maker

def index(request):
    context = {
        "leagues": League.objects.all(),
        "teams": Team.objects.all(),
        "players": Player.objects.all(),
        "baseball" : League.objects.filter(sport__contains="Baseball"),
        "women" : League.objects.filter(name__contains="Womens'"),
        "ice" : League.objects.filter(sport__contains="ice"),
        "nofootball" : League.objects.exclude(sport__contains="football"),
        "conferences" : League.objects.filter(name__contains="conference"),
        "atlantic": League.objects.filter(name__contains="Atlantic"),
        "teamdallas": Team.objects.filter(location__contains="Dallas"),
        "raptor": Team.objects.filter(team_name__contains="Raptor"),
        "cityloc": Team.objects.filter(location__contains="city"),
        "startT": Team.objects.filter(team_name__startswith="T"),
        "abc": Team.objects.order_by('location'),
        "cba": Team.objects.order_by('location').reverse(),
        "cooper": Player.objects.filter(last_name="Cooper"),
        "joshua": Player.objects.filter(first_name="Joshua"),
        "nocooper": Player.objects.filter(last_name="Cooper").exclude(first_name="Joshua"),
        "wyatt": Player.objects.filter(first_name="Alexander")|Player.objects.filter(first_name="Wyatt"),
        "atlanticsoccer" : Team.objects.filter(league__name__contains='atlantic', league__sport__contains="soccer"),
        "bostonp" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__team_name__contains='Penguins'),
        "icbc" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__league__name__contains='International Collegiate Baseball '),
        "footballlopez" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__league__name__contains="American Conference of Amateur Football", last_name__contains="lopez"),
        "footballplayer" : Player.objects.filter(curr_team__league__sport__contains="football"),
        "sophia" : Team.objects.filter(curr_players__first_name__contains='sophia'),
        "sophiale" :League.objects.filter(teams__curr_players__first_name__contains='sophia'),
      "notrough" :Player.objects.filter(last_name__contains='Flores').exclude(curr_team__team_name__contains='rough'),
      "sevans" :Team.objects.filter(all_players__first_name__contains='Samuel'),
      "Tiger" :Player.objects.filter(all_teams__team_name__contains='Tiger'),
      "vikings":Player.objects.filter(all_teams__team_name__contains='vikings'),
      "jgray":Team.objects.filter(all_players__first_name__contains='Jacob').exclude(team_name__contains='colts'),
      "joshua":Player.objects.filter(all_teams__league__name__contains='Atlantic Federation of Amateur Baseball')&Player.objects.filter(first_name='Joshua'),
      "num12":Player.objects.annotate(num13=)



    }

        return render(request, "leagues/index.html", context)

def make_data(request):
    team_maker.gen_leagues(10)
    team_maker.gen_teams(50)
    team_maker.gen_players(200)

    return redirect("index")

models.py

from django.db import models

class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, related_name="teams")

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    curr_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="curr_players")
    all_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name="all_players")
```

Comment: `Team.objects.annotate(c=Count('player')).filter(s__gt=12')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Team.objects.annotate(c=Count('all_players')).filter(c__gt=12')
```

What this would do is:

1. In each record/row in the `Team` model/table it will append/annotate a new value. The `c` one. You can name it whatever you like. This `c` will be the number of `player`s this `row`/`record` is associated with.
2. Then, since the `c` value is annotated in all rows, it will filter those and get all rows which have `c` greater that 12 (`player`s).

Comment: the player throws an error shoudl it be all_players   Cannot resolve keyword 'player' into field. Choices are: all_players, curr_players, id, league, league_id, location, team_name

Comment: ty again worth a million